# Conversion of a Char variable to an integer

Tags: c#

why is the integer equivalent of '8' is 56 in C sharp? I want to convert it to an integer 8 and not any other number.

Comment: Pretty much any language that uses ASCII or Unicode behaves this way - characters are codes for symbols to be displayed, not digits to use directly in computations.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to subtract the offset from `'0'`.

```
int zero = (int)'0'; // 48
int eight = (int)'8'; // 56
int value = eight - zero; // 8
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can just write `int value = myChar - '0';`. Even though `myChar` and `'0'` are both of type `char`, the result of the subtraction operator is of type `int`.

Comment: No need to cast.  `int value = '8' - '0';`

Comment: @Timwi, @Matthew - I felt that explicitness better answered this question.

Answer (score 3):

56 is the (EDIT) Unicode value for the character 8 use:

```
Int32.Parse(myChar.ToString());
```

EDIT:

OR this:

```
        char myChar = '8';
        Convert.ToInt32(myChar);
```

Comment: Except that C# is a unicode language, not an ASCII one. Coincidentally, 56 is the code point for '8' in Unicode as well.

Comment: int32.parse(mychar) works only if mychar is a string and not a character

Comment: I would advice against calling Char.ToString to convert single character to integer. But is is definitely the right way if you need to read numbers, not individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of converting unicode characters in C#/.Net is to use corresponding Char methods IsDigit and GetNumericValue  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz.aspx).

If you are absolutely sure that there will be no non-ASCII numbers in your input than ChaosPandion's suggestion is fine too.